# Retrieve data from another program into VBA

Tags: vba, api, excel

I'm trying to retrieve data from another software, called CMA Series 4 into my Excel. I already was able to get a handler for the chart i wanna retrieve that data, but from now, i have no idea how to proceed to obtain that information.

Using Microsoft Spy ++, i was able to sucessfully acess the object in CMA, that is from "fpSpread 60" class. But how do i retrieve the data stored in it? That's the code:

```
Sub GetBookData()

Dim BookTitle As String
Dim BookClass As String

'----------------------------------------------------------'
BookTitle = "[012] POMO4 - Livro de Ofertas"
'----------------------------------------------------------'

hwnd = FindWindow("CMAGRAPHIC_MDI", vbNullString)
    Livro1 = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0&, "MDIClient", vbNullString)
    Livro2 = FindWindowEx(Livro1, 0&, vbNullString, BookTitle) 'Classe alterável
    Livro3 = FindWindowEx(Livro2, 0&, "SysTabControl32", vbNullString)
    Livro4 = FindWindowEx(Livro3, 0&, "AfxMDIFrame90", vbNullString)

    'Necessaria criação dessa porcaria dessa árvore de referencia porque a estrutura desse lixo de CMA é essa...
    Livro5 = FindWindowEx(Livro4, 0&, "AfxFrameOrView90", vbNullString)
        Livro6 = FindWindowEx(Livro4, Livro5, "AfxFrameOrView90", vbNullString)
        Livro7 = FindWindowEx(Livro4, Livro6, "AfxFrameOrView90", vbNullString)
        Livro8 = FindWindowEx(Livro4, Livro7, "AfxFrameOrView90", vbNullString)
        Livro9 = FindWindowEx(Livro4, Livro8, "AfxFrameOrView90", vbNullString)
        Livro10 = FindWindowEx(Livro4, Livro9, "AfxFrameOrView90", vbNullString)

    Livro11 = FindWindowEx(Livro10, 0&, "fpSpread60", vbNullString)
        Livro12 = FindWindowEx(Livro10, Livro11, "fpSpread60", vbNullString)
        Livro13 = FindWindowEx(Livro10, Livro12, "fpSpread60", vbNullString)
        Livro14 = FindWindowEx(Livro10, Livro13, "fpSpread60", vbNullString)
        Livro15 = FindWindowEx(Livro10, Livro14, "fpSpread60", vbNullString)
        HwndBook = FindWindowEx(Livro10, Livro15, "fpSpread60", vbNullString) '---- FINALMENTE ----'


'MsgBox HwndBook
MsgBox HwndBook

End Sub
```

And, i'm posting also a print screen from the place i wanna grab that info:

[CMA Series 4 Chart](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/7043/yeo3nE.png)

Comment: can you make a simple loop that goes through all the objects?  Maybe using the Object class you can derive some of the basic class functions.

Comment: Hello, Holmes, Thanks for the answer! But how can use that object class?

Comment: I've found a manual about the class. The link is here, but i have no idea how tu use that messages... http://download.componentone.com/pub/product/dllref.pdf